# Golang FormFile unit test

Tags: unit-testing, http, go

I have the following function:

```
func CreateByID(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    formFile, _, err := r.FormFile("audio")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer formFile.Close()
    defer r.MultipartForm.RemoveAll()

    tmpFile, err := os.CreateTemp("/tmp")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer os.Remove(tmpFile.Name())
    io.Copy(tmpFile, formFile)

    err = validateFile(tmpFile.Name())
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}

func validateFile(path string) error {
    fs, err := os.Stat(path)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    if fs.Size() < allowedSize {
       return fmt.Errorf("file is too small")
    }
}
```

which is basically creating a temp file from the HTTP request and validating it before further processing. This works fine except for the unit test. When I'm testing this function - I'm getting always filesize = 0.

Below you can see the Test case:

```
func TestCreateByID(t *testing.T) {
    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(pw)

    go func() {
        defer writer.Close()
        _, err := writer.CreateFormFile("audio", "/tmp/audioFile")
        if err != nil {
            t.Error(err)
        }
        generateAudioSample("/tmp/audioFile")
    }()

    request := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/{id}")
    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

    response := httptest.NewRecorder()

    # Calling The Actual Function
    CreateByID(response, request)

    handler := http.NewServeMux()
    handler.ServeHTTP(response, request)

    if response.Code != 200 {
        t.Errorf("Expected %d, received %d", 200, response.Code)
        return
    }
}
```

generateAudioSample function is working fine because I can see the file on the filesystem and its size it bigger than 0 but for some reason this function `io.Copy(tmpFile, formFile)` doesn't seem to handle FormFile correctly, and is creating just an empty file on the filesystem and obviously fail the test. What else should I add to the test function in order to pass the test?

Comment: The client does not write data to the form file (the return value from CreateFormFile is ignored).  Add code to copy the generated sample file to the form file.